# Can not run basic LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am missing something very basic, I don't know what... I get an exception on following Linq:

```
Dim arch As List(Of String)
'gets archive as String() and casts it as List
arch = client.GetArchive().ToList() 
'here exception occurs: Cannot cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2'...
arch = From a In arch
       Where a.EndsWith(System.Environment.UserName & ".htm")
       Select a
```

Comment: A LINQ query returns an `IENumerable(Of T)`, not a `List`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in this case the where returns an iterator type, if i was select it would return IEnumerable

Comment: Your second LINQ query is just a _query_, it's not executed until you call a method like `ToList`, `ToArray`, `First` or any other method that is not using deferred execution(like `Where`, `Select`, `Skip`,...). Always keep that in mind. So store the query in another variable(f.e. `htmlArchives`). Then you can create a `List(Of String)` with `htmlArchives.ToList()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as it states, you're trying to store a where iterator to a list.

Try this:

```
arch = arch.where(Function(x)x.EndsWith(System.Environment.UserName & ".htm")).ToList()
```

I prefer extension linq, but it's just preference, and the reason mine will work is because of the `ToList()` :)

Comment: In VB.NET i prefer query syntax, more powerful than in C# and no ugly `Function`-keyword everywhere.